Prepare Cohort Analysis table in Excel
I have Sales data that I want to run a Cohort analysis on, meaning I want to track all customers that started in a given month (="cohort") over time and compare them with all customers that started a month later, and so on.
For each cohort I have revenue data for each given month (A, B, C, ...), see the lefthand side format in this pic:

Now I want to convert this table into the righthand side format to compare each cohort's respective first month ("A"), each cohort's second month ("B"), and so on.
Is there an easy way to do this conversion, this kind of left-aligning of the data, in Excel?
Thank you!

An alternative could be REDUCE and LAMBDA however for huge datasets there are performance issues.
=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:J10)),LAMBDA(u,v,
VSTACK(u,DROP(INDEX(B2:J10,v,),,COUNTBLANK(INDEX(B2:J10,v,)))))),1),"")



Here is one way to accomplish the desired output using MAKEARRAY()


=LET(
     _Data, A2:J10,
     _ColOne, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Rows, ROWS(_ColOne),
     _RevData, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _Output, IFERROR(MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Rows,LAMBDA(r,c,
              INDEX(TOROW(IF((INDEX(_ColOne,r)=_ColOne)*(_RevData<>""),_RevData,0/0),2),c))),""),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_Output))),HSTACK(_ColOne, _Output)))


